# liferay force theme refresh

Tags: themes, liferay, liferay-6, portlet

I have created theme. In this, If user logs in then he got to see his name , image etc above header. 
It also contains edit profile link which redirects to page where I have placed 'Edit User' portlet. This is my custom portlet.

For showing user details in theme I have used code as:

```
       <span>Welcome </span>
        <span class="userName">$user_name</span>
        <img alt="image"  src="$user.getPortraitURL($themeDisplay)"/>
        <a href="/myprofile">Edit Profile</a>
        <a href="$sign_out_url">Logout</a>
```

Edit user is a spring portlet, I have used action request for updating the user.

```
liferayUser = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUser(themeDisplay.getUserId());
String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
String email = request.getParameter("email");
if(liferayUser != null)
            {

                liferayUser.setFirstName(firstName);
                liferayUser.setLastName(lastName);
                liferayUser.setEmailAddress(email); 

                liferayUser.setModifiedDate(new Date());
                liferayUser = UserLocalServiceUtil.updateUser(liferayUser);
                logger.error(":::LR User updated:::");   }
```

My page is getting refreshed, user is getting updated I can able to see response on text box. But I can not able to see the changed value in the theme.

For getting the value, I have to refresh the page. In short $user_name is not getting updated value over my action. As I can able to see same name in liferay's accordion.

Is there any way to reload the theme on any action in the portlet.

I am using liferay 6.2 version.

Thanks in Advance